# Using multi-cursor to insert text at different columns on multiple lines

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code (with vim plugin), how would I insert text after the first word of each sentence on multiple lines?  I would like to know how to do this strictly with multi-cursor, not macros, search/replace, etc.

I would like to turn this:

```
Hi how are you?
Ahoy how are you?
Howdy how are you?
```

into this:

```
Hi, how are you?
Ahoy, how are you?
Howdy, how are you?
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a single command

```
:%norm ea,

: ................... command mode
% ................... whole file
norm  ............... normal mode
e  .................. end of a word
a  .................. append charactere
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to select your lines with `Selection/Column Selection Mode` enabled.  Select the first column (there are other ways to get a cursor at the beginning of each of your selected lines - such as

(1)  Select all your lines

(2)  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to put a cursor at the end of each line

(3)  <kbd>Home</kbd> to move all those to the beginning

Then you'll need to bind this command

`cursorWordPartRight`

to some keybinding.  Trigger that keybinding and type your `,`.